# Do I need to deserialize the query result from DocumentDb?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, azure-cosmosdb

I have a simple POCO for person object that looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
   public int PersonId {get; set;}
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string MiddleName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
   public char Gender {get; set;}
}
```

I have the following code that queries the People collection in my DocumentDb database.

```
private async static Task<List<Person>> GetPeopleList(string colSelfLink)
{
   dynamic doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(colSelfLink, "SELECT p.PersonId, p.FirstName, p.MiddleName, p.LastName, p.Gender FROM People p").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
   List<Person> peopleList = new List<Person>();
   if (doc != null)
   {
      peopleList = doc;
   }
   return peopleList;
}
```

When I run this code, I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type     'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyApp.Person]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'PersonId', line 1, position
>       48.

How do I convert the JSON object coming from my query to a Person object? In my MVC app, the model binder does a pretty good job but this is running in a separate class library. How should I approach converting this JSON object?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` returns a single object (or null). Its result can't be assigned to a list.

Comment: I see your point so I changed FirstOrDefault() to ToList() but still having an issue. I now get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.GenericList<Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document>' to 'System.Collections.GenericList<MyApp.Person>'" error.

How do I handle the conversion? Do I need to have a foreach and handle converting each document to a Person object? I tried that too but failed.

Comment: I think I got it. Looks like I need to do a foreach loop and deserialize the document/json object into my POCO class.

Is this the right approach? It worked for me but I want to make sure there's no better way to do it.

Comment: I haven't used DocumentDb yet, but I would think this might be all you need? `List<Person> peopleList = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Person>(colSelfLink, "...").AsEnumerable().ToList();`

Answer (score 7):

This is what I did and it works. I'd appreciate other answers though if there's a better way.

```
private async static Task<List<Person>> GetPeopleList(string colSelfLink)
{
   dynamic doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(colSelfLink, "SELECT p.PersonId, p.FirstName, p.MiddleName, p.LastName, p.Gender FROM People p").AsEnumerable().ToList();
   List<Person> peopleList = new List<Person>();
   if (doc != null)
   {
      Person person;
      foreach(var item in doc)
      {
         person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(item.ToString());
         peopleList.Add(person);
      }
   }
   return peopleList;
}
```

Comment: Best thing I've found. I played with dozens of different ways and got nothing to work.

Comment: I did this as well, however I'm steering away from it. The problem with `.ToString()` is you're at the mercy of DocumentDB SDK Resource class's overriding (or not) of `.ToString()`. What may serve you better is to first `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item)` and then deserialise it to your POCO.

Answer (score 4):

Anthony Chu was on the right track with this one. The simple solution is:

```
private async static Task<List<Person>> GetPeopleList(string colSelfLink)
{
   return client.CreateDocumentQuery<Person>(colSelfLink, "SELECT * FROM People").ToList();
}
```

This will automatically deserialise each returned record and turn it into a People object.

Comment: what if there are multiple document formats in a collection? entirely possible given that in cosmos db collections are essentially just "buckets" for documents.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem, only that my list of objects failing, was nested in another object (document).

```
public List<MyObject> MyProperty { get; set; }
```

I am so happy right now that I found the solution:

If you have lists of complex objects in your document, put this on the properties of the complex object:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "yourPropertyName")]
```

This is well known to be needed on the primary object (document), haven't needed them on nested objects though, until they were in a list.